# Como verificar a existência de uma pasta?

Tags: c, c++

Como verificar a existência de uma pasta com um programa C/C++, ele procura pelo diretório, caso não achar o diretório especificado, ele irá tomar a decisão de cria-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O melhor jeito de se fazer isso, é usando o `opendir`, essa função funciona igual o `fopen`, se não encontra o "item" desejado retorna ***NULL***.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    int fd = open("/usr/", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    DIR *d1 = fdopendir(fd);

    DIR *d2 = opendir("/etc");
    DIR *d3 = opendir("main.c");

    printf("%i-%i-%i\n", d1, d2, d3);

    if(!d1) puts("d1 não é um diretório ou não existe.");
    else mkdir("/usr/");

    if(!d2) puts("d2 não é um diretório ou não existe.");
    else mkdir("/usr/");

    if(!d3) puts("d3 não é um diretório ou não existe.");

    close(d1);
    close(d2);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Os diretórios podem ser abertos usando o retorno da função `open`, ou diretamente (isso depende da preferencia ou necessidade).

---

Já o *Windows* possui o `GetFileAttributes`

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL DirectoryExists(LPCTSTR path)
{
  DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(path);

  return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && 
         (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    if(DirectoryExists("c:/Windows"))
        puts("O diretório existe!");
    else
        mkdir("c:/Windows");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "opendir" não é padrão nem do C nem do C++, e não existe no Windows,
Além disso, de acordo com a pergunta feita a melhor solução é simplesmente criar o diretório; caso o diretório já exista a tentativa de criá-lo novamente vai retornar erro.

Comment: Corrigi para verificar no Windows também. O `mkdir` pode resolver esse problema, mas caso apareçam problemas que não é viável usá-lo, é bom também conhecer outros meios.

Comment: de maneira geral não é aconselhável "testar e depois usar", porque no intervalo de tempo entre "testar" e "usar", o resultado do teste pode ter perdido a validade...isso é um "anti-pattern" conhecido como TOCTOU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: realmente isso pode consumir um tempo extra, mas no caso, é apenas um material didático, o foco é aprender a usar as funcionalidades da linguagem, fazer uma análise de performasse e tempo de resposta já é algo mais profissional. não acho que isso se encaixe nesse contesto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar direto o `mkdir`, se o diretório existir ele irá retornar -1, se o diretório não existir ele será criado e retorna 0

Um detalhe que esqueci de mencionar em relação ao uso direto do `mkdir`, é a performace.... Se você precisa verificar muitas pastas e caso não tenha ir criando aconselho o uso do segundo código

Código para checar se existe e criar caso não exista:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    int f = mkdir("C:/Pasta");

    if (f == -1)
       puts("Diretório já existe.");
    else
       puts("Diretório criado.");

    return 0;
}
```

Código automatizar a criação de pasta:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    int tam = 2;
    char *pastas[tam];
    pastas[0] = "pasta1";
    pastas[1] = "pasta2";

    for (int i = 0, i < tam, i++)
        mkdir(pastas[i]);

    return 0;
}
```